# How to save webpage as web archive and then display the web archive as a webpage using Android's WebView?

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I am developing an Android application in Android Studio 3.0.1, Xubuntu 16.04 LTS, using a WebView as a wrapper for a responsive web app that contains HTML, CSS, JavaScript/jQuery and uses PHP/MySQL for the backend. Almost everything is working as expected: the pages fully render, JavaScript runs and the sign-up/login/news-feed systems work as they should.

But now I would like to implement some kind of simple caching system, so that the user can still see the last available version of the pages when there's no Internet connection.

As of now, I've managed to detect whether there is Internet connection; In case there's no connection, the WebView displays a local "Error" page, stored in the app files - which is better than the default Android "Connection Error" screen, but still the user can't see the images and text posts from the news feed when offline like in the Facebook app.

What I have tried (Java/Android Studio):

**When the user opens the app (onCreate)**:

- If there's no connection, check for a locally saved version of the page it's trying to retrieve; If there is connection, save the page as a .mht file for the next time:

  ```
  if (!isConnected()) {

      try {

          File file = new File(getFilesDir(), FilenameUtils.getBaseName(url));
          webView.loadUrl("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath() + ".mht");

      } catch (Exception e) {

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }

  } else {

      try {

          File file = new File(getFilesDir(), FilenameUtils.getBaseName(url));
          webView.loadUrl(url);
          webView.saveWebArchive("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath() + ".mht");

      } catch (Exception e) {

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }

  }
  ```

I have tried using `webView.saveWebArchive()` with different paths, including simple `/path/to/file`, `file:///path/to/file`, etc., to no avail. The closest I got to displaying something on the WebView was a bunch of raw MHTML, but apparently it wasn't rendered. I also got "File not found" screens and plain white screens without anything on them.

How can I properly save a web page from a WebView into a web archive, and then retrieve from the local storage and display it as a web page again?

**Edit:**

As suggested by greenapps in the comments, I overrode the "onPageFinished" method in the WebViewClient and called "saveWebArchive()" there:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String link) {

    view.saveWebArchive(path);
    showMsg("Finished loading");

}
```

When the phone is connected to the Internet and the home page loads, it does show "Finished loading". After closing the app, disconnecting and opening it again, it now shows a blank background with the color of the original page, no more white pages or error messages. But there aren't any images, text or anything.

Comment: Those are two questions. Lets keep it at one first. Can jou save it in a valid mht file?

Comment: `webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.saveWebArchive("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath() + ".mht");`. You cannot save the page there. Too early. The page is not yet loaded. Do it in onPageLoaded() or in onPageFinished(). However that method is called.

Comment: @greenapps OK will do.

Comment: What is the fille lenght of the mht file? Please transfer to computer and display in pc browsers.

Comment: That's quite strange. I was saving the files to Internal storage, so now I changed to External storage. When the application starts, a toast shows the value of "path". When set to External storage, it shows /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxx/files/home.mht. When I try to access this file via USB cable/file explorer in my computer, there's nothing in that directory. But when I show the contents of the dir with File.listDirectory(), everything is there.

Comment: By the way, uses-permission for External Storage is set in AndroidManifest.xml; but when I access the phone's Settings > Applications > My app, it shows nothing under "permissions".

Comment: That you do not yet see it on your pc comes while you did not tell the mediastore about the new file. You could do that. But you could also wait a day and then the media scanner has found the file and your pc has access. If you reboot your device the pc can see it directly...

Comment: `it shows nothing under "permissions"` Click on it and then you can toggle Storage. But you do not need any permission for that path. Which Android version in use?

Comment: Use a file explorer app on your device to see the file.

Comment: Another update: Apparently I have set Internal storage as default in my phone's settings, so when I refer to "getExternalFilesDir(null)" in Java it's actually pointing to the Internal storage (quite confusing). Yes, the file is there (home.mht), and when I try to render it with Chrome in my PC it does open and everything is there. But the layout is a bit different, so things do not appear in the mobile screen as they should. Apparently saveWebArchive() is taking a "snapshot" right in the middle of a jQuery animation, when an overlay div is on top of the page.

Comment: Android version is 7.0, API 24. Maybe I could "sleep" for a few miliseconds before saving the archive?

Comment: Do what you want. But maybe the save is asynchonous and then you can better make a button to test. But if all is there... then what is the problem? Did you try Chrome on your device already?

Comment: Well, sleeping for two seconds actually worked. The full page is now showing when offline. Thank you very much for your time and patience. I'm going to post an answer so other people can see this.

Comment: Feel free to do that. I'll mark it as the answer if you post it. I wrote an answer so that I can have a solution for this same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webView.loadUrl(url); 
webView.saveWebArchive("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath() + ".mht");.
```

You cannot save the page there.

Too early.

The page is not yet loaded.

Do it in onPageLoaded() or in onPageFinished().

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you need to wait for the page to finish loading before attempting to save it to an archive.

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
webView.saveWebArchive(path);
```

won't work since the page isn't fully loaded yet. So you need to override the "onPageFinished" method in your WebViewClient in order to save the archive only when the page is finished:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        if (isConnected()) {

            try {

                Thread.sleep(2000);
                view.saveWebArchive(path_to_saveDir);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

    }

});
```

Note that I've used `Thread.sleep(2000)` because there is a jQuery animation when the page loads, so it waits 2 seconds for the animation to finish, then saves the web archive.